# Peculiar Jquery behavior when using .effects()

Tags: jquery

I was trying to use .effect( "bounce", "slow" ) on a div but three more divs appeared instead. 
The problem is quite hard to explain in text, so I have included a JSFiddle link at the bottom.

I wasn't sure if it was my code so I copied the entire source directly from the documentation to JSFiddle and got the same result.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryBjh/

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>effect demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click anywhere to apply the effect.</p>
<div></div>

<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
    $( "div" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tested on Chrome
Script works normally on ie8 and firefox... so is this a chrome bug?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently chrome added extra divs into the page,  and then applied css styles and animations to all the div elements.
It looks like there's only 1 div, but the browser had inserted a couple of it's own.

I changed the code so it would only affect a the .box class and everything worked as intended.

Here is the new code that works on all browsers:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>effect demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
   .box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click anywhere to apply the effect.</p>
<div class= 'box' ></div>

<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
    $( ".box" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>​
```